Next js app router, redirecting to homepage if already logged in
I am using next-auth in Nextjs to authenticate to a web application I created. If the user is already logged in when I'm I navigate to /login route, I should be redirected to the home page. This is the code I have used to achieve that.
'use client'


import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

function Login() {
    const sessionData = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log('sessionData:', sessionData)
    if (sessionData.status == "authenticated") {
        router.push("/pages/list-clients");
    } else {
        if (sessionData.status === "loading") {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        } else {
            signIn("keycloak")
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error occurred during sign in KeyCloak:", error);
                });
        }
    }
}

export default Login

But when I am using this I am having below error.

Cannot update a component (Router) while rendering a different component (Login). To locate the bad setState() call inside Login, follow the stack trace as described in https://react.dev/link/setstate-in-render


For the reference this is my layout.tsx, Auth.tsx and Provider.tsx

layout.tsx

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  component: Component
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  component: any
}>) {
  // console.log('Im, component, ', Component)
  // console.log(requiresAuth)
  const requiresAuth = Component?.requiresAuth || true;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable}`}>
        <Providers>
          {requiresAuth ? 
              <Auth>
                <TopNavbar />
                {children}
                <Footer />
              </Auth>
            : children
          }
        </Providers> 
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


Auth.tsx

const Auth = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
      if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
          signIn("keycloak")
              .catch(error => {
                  console.error("Error occurred during sign in KeyCloak:", error);
              });
      }
  }, [status, router]);

  if (status === 'loading') {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!session) {
      return <div>Redirecting...</div>;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default Auth;


Providers.tsx

"use client";
import {SessionProvider} from "next-auth/react";

export function Providers({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}

What am I missing here? This approach for Login component worked when I used the page route approach.
